# How to filter out data that is set to a state in react

Tags: reactjs, api, filter, use-state

I'm trying to build a search function that displays items that match the searchTerm. The data I am getting is from an API, I want filter out all items apart from the searchedTerm item, the initial API call runs once, with useEffect and [] callback

```js
const changeFilterItem = (values) => {
    const data = [...item];
    const index = data.indexOf(values);
    if (index > -1) {
      data.splice(index, 1);
    } else {
      data.push(values);
    }
    setItem([...data]);
};

useEffect(() => {
    if (item !== null) {
        setLoading(true);
        let pokemonList = [];
        async function fetchData() {
            for (let i = 0; i < item.length; i++) {
                let response = await getAllPokemonByType(initialURLType, item[i]);
                const pokemons = [...response.pokemon, ...pokemonList];
                pokemonList = pokemons.slice(0);
            }
            console.log(pokemonList);
            await loadPokemonByFilter(pokemonList);
        }
        fetchData().then();
    }
}, [item]);

const loadPokemonByFilter = async (data) => {
    let _pokemonData = await Promise.all(
      data.map(async (pokemon) => {
        return await getPokemon(pokemon.pokemon);
      })
    );
    setPokemonData(_pokemonData);
    setLoading(false);
};

const renderSelected = (type) => {
    if (item.indexOf(type) === -1) {
      return "";
    }
    return classes.selected;
};
```

Comment: This will be _way_ easier to help with if we can see your current code. Filtering out data sounds like something calling `.filter()` on an `Array` can help with, but we don't know what you're starting from.

Comment: @Jacob i've added code as to how i filter by type of pokemon, but i want to do the same but with a search bar, not sure on how to go about doing that

Answer (score 0):

What i've understood so far is that you want to filter out data from an array that has some data. For that you can use matchSorter. 
Here is the link for its docs: 
https://github.com/kentcdodds/match-sorter

Answer (score 0):

```
const [master, setMaster] = React.useState([]);
const [filtered, setFiltered] = React.useState([]);

React.useEffect(() => {
  makeApiCall().then(response => {
    setMaster(response);
    setFiltered(response);
  });
}, []);

function filterData() {
  setFiltered(master.filter(n => n.name === 'valueFromTextInput' && n.age === 'valueFromTextInput'));
}
```

Use `filtered` to your data grid where you want to show data. Call `filterData` function from your function where you want to do filtering.

Hope it helps.